# calling merge sort of my linked list on my main

Tags: c, linked-list, mergesort

I'm new to C and I have a question to ask.

I am creating a linked list that has this struct:

```
 struct node
 {
      char data[100];
      struct node *previous;  // Points to the previous node
      struct node *next;   // Points out to the next node
 }*head, *last;
```

And I'm asked on my code to add a function to sort my list as well.
I used a code called merge sort algorithm to test and understand it's function. Now I would like to call it on my main but don't know how.

This is my function name:

```
struct node *merge_sort(struct node *head)
```

Now if let's say I call it on my `main()` how should I do that?
let me know if I'm not asking the question well.

Thanks

Comment: Just call `merge_sort(head)` from your main program.

Comment: `head=merge_sort(head);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call will be like,

```
merge_sort(head);
```

Comment: I'm posting this i'm still having problems.
http://ideone.com/e.js/HqvaQy

any help?

Comment: First you need to tell me, what problem are you having?

Comment: case 8 is not working it's just displaying back what i have and didn't sort anything

Comment: is someone can propose a better way to use merge sort please let me know if you have example links to view. as i'm new to c i need to understand how to do it

Comment: Your problem is in merge() function comparison was not done rightly. To compare C style strings you need to use strcmp() function. Not relational operators. Here it goes. It's working now. Take a look at line no# 230. http://paste.ubuntu.com/6662076/

Comment: amazing thank you so much i'll have a look to understand it better

Comment: Note that the call will be even more like: `head = merge_sort(head);` since, in general, the original first element in the list will not be the first element of the sorted list.